# regex problem C#

Tags: c#, regex

```
const string strRegex = @"(?<city_country>.+) (cca|ca.|ungefähr) (?<price>[\d.,]+) (eur)?";
            searchQuery = RemoveSpacesFromString(searchQuery);
            Regex regex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            Match m = regex.Match(searchQuery);
            ComplexAdvertismentsQuery query = new ComplexAdvertismentsQuery();

            if (m.Success)
            {
                query.CityOrAreaName = m.Groups["city_country"].Value;
                query.CountryName = m.Groups["city_country"].Value;
                query.Price = Convert.ToDecimal(m.Groups["price"].Value);
            }
            else
                return null;
```

ca. must be for example only 1 times but the word "Agadir ca. ca. 600 eur" is also correct even if "ca." is 2 times. Why? i do not use + or ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with previous topic it gets into `city_country` group. Try to replace `(?<city_country>.+)` with `(?<city_country>[^.]+)`. It will match everything except `.`. I guess your `city_country` couldn't have dots inside?

Comment: This is corret. Can you explain me little better. Thx. Why [^.]+

Comment: Well, your case just says - I match any count (`+` at the end) of any character (`.` matches one any char). My example says - I match any count of any character except `.`. Because `.` in square brackets loose its special meaning and `^` means "anything except characters in braces".

Comment: Or use even more restrictive regex for your city_country. As Pop suggested below, for example. But his example doesn't match spaces. It could be a problem, but it is your decision. I don't know your details.

Answer (score 1):

. (Dot) Mathes anything in Regex even spaces which leads to the problem

So your matches are:

1. `@"(?<city_country>.+):Agadir ca.`
2. `(cca|ca.|ungefähr): ca.`
3. `(?<price>[\d.,]+) (eur)?:600 eur`

You need to match the city name withouth using the dot, for example something like:

```
@"(?<city_country>[a-zA-Z]+) (cca|ca.|ungefähr) (?<price>[\d.,]+) (eur)?"
```